# Abel's theorem proof

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I was looking at a proof of Abel's theorem saying that a degree zero divisor on a compact riemann surface is principal iff $A_0(D)=0$ using cohomology. I have the following diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
@.0@.0\\
@.@VVV@VVV\\ 
@.PDiv(X)@.PDiv(X)\\
@.@VVV@VVV\\
0 @>>> Div_0(X) @>>> Div(X) @>deg>>\mathbb{Z}  @>>> 0 \\
@. @VA_0 VV\# @V V V @VV V @. \\
0  @>>> {\frac{H^1(X,O_X)}{H^1(X,\mathbb{Z})}}=Jac(X) @>>{f}> {H^1(X,O_X^*)} @>>{}> {H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})} @>>> 0\\
\end{CD}

Where the last row comes from the long exact sequence in cohomology relative to the exponential sequence, the second row is obviously exact and the second column comes from the long exact sequence in cohomology relative to the short exact sequence $0\rightarrow O^*\rightarrow M^* \rightarrow M^*/O^*\rightarrow 0$ (it is the same as saying cartier divisor and weil divisor coincide in this case). Now I want to prove that the first column is exact implying the conclusion of the theorem, to do that I would use diagram chasing and to do that I need the diagram to commuted so it would easily follow that the first column is exact. **So my question is how to prove that the square with the # commutes**.

**Addition to what I said above:**

Considering the square # we see that taking $D=\sum p_i-\sum q_i\in Div_0X$ it is sent via $A_0$ to $(\sum_i\int_{p_i}^{q_i} \omega_j)_{j}$ modulo $\Lambda\cong H^1(X,\mathbb{Z})$, where $\omega_1,...,\omega_g$ is a basis of $H^1(X,O_X)$.The horizontal map is simply the inclusion sending $D$ to itself inside $DivX$ and the other vertical map is the map sending $D$ to its class $[D]$ inside $Pic(X)$. **My problem is to understand what actually is the map $f$ in order to prove the diagrm is commutative**.

I am really interested in this proof I found on Rick Miranda book on algebraic curves and riemann surfaces because it seems to me very beautiful, but it lacks in details about the commutativity of the diagram (it doesn't even mention it) and in this case the commutativity of the diagram is crucial (the rest follows with easy cohomological arguments and trivial diagram chasing). Hence any help will be much apprecited.

Comment: More precisely $A_0$ sends $\sum_i n_i p_i \in Div_0(X)$ to $(\sum_i n_i \int_a^{p_i} \omega_1,\ldots, \sum_i n_i \int_a^{p_i} \omega_{g}) + \Lambda \in Jac(X) = \mathbb{C}^g/\Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is the rank $2g$ lattice $\{ (\int_\gamma \omega_1,\ldots,\int_\gamma \omega_{g}), \gamma$ closed-loop$\} \subset \mathbb{C}^g$ and $\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_{g}$ is a fixed basis of the space of holomorphic differentials $\Omega_X$. And $f$ could be just the identity with path integrals seen as elements of $\Omega_X^*$

Comment: I have edited to be more precise. I am interested in your last line, could you explain it better? You send $(\sum_i n_i \int_a^{p_i} \omega_1,\ldots, \sum_i n_i \int_a^{p_i} \omega_{g})$ to where in $H^1(X,O_X^*)\cong Pic(X)\cong Div(X)/PDiv(X)$?                                                              
(Also for the degree zero divisor you don't need to fix a base point to define the abel-jacobi map since it is independent of the base point)

Comment: Abel's theorem states that divisors of meromorphic functions are the kernel of $A_0$, so $A_0$ induces an isomorphism $Pic^0(X) \to Jac(X)$

Comment: It is not clear to me why f is the identity. If I prove the diagram commutes by diagram chasing the first column is exact and so we have abel's theorem which is equivalent to prove $KerA_0=Im(PdivX\hookrightarrow Div_0X)$.

Comment: About the kernel of $A_0$, did you look at things like $\int_\gamma (\log f ) \omega$ for $f \in \mathbb{C}(X)$ ?

Comment: What do you want to do, proving that $KerA_0=Im(PdivX\hookrightarrow Div_0X)$ directly or proving that the diagram commutes so that it will follow by diagram chasing?

Comment: It is not clear to me how you will obtain $\ker A_0$ by another mean. I think evaluating $\int_\gamma (\log f) \omega$ in two different ways, with $\gamma$ the boundary of a fundamental domain for $X$ (in its covering space) implies directly $A_0(\text{div}(f))  \in \Lambda$